# How to search multiple worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I search any text within Worksheet2 and display the results in ListBox1.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

    'ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.RowSource = ""
    ListBox1.ColumnHeads = False

    'listbox column headers
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem
    For A = 1 To 8
        Me.ListBox1.List(0, A - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, A)
    Next A
    Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

    'Populating listbox from search
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        For j = 1 To 8
            H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A" & i, "H" & i), Sheet2.Cells(i, j))
            If H = 1 And LCase(Sheet2.Cells(i, j)) = LCase(Me.TextBox2) Or H = 1 And _
                Sheet2.Cells(i, j) = Val(Me.TextBox2) Then
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                    For X = 1 To 8
                        Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, X - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, X)
                    Next X
            End If
       Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

I want to search multiple worksheets instead but don't know how to achieve this without changing the code completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to change the reference to `Sheet2` if you want to look at multiple sheets. There's no way around that. But, it will make your code more flexible. Start by doing this:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

'ListBox1.Clear
    ListBox1.RowSource = ""
    ListBox1.ColumnHeads = False

'listbox column headers
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
 For A = 1 To 8
 Me.ListBox1.List(0, A - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, A)
 Next A
 Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

Dim ws As Worksheet             'This is the new line of code where you define your worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet2  'Replace all references below to Sheet2 with this

 'Populating listbox from search
 Dim i As Long

 For i = 2 To ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
 For j = 1 To 8
 H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("A" & i, "H" & i), Sheet2.Cells(i, j))
 If H = 1 And LCase(Sheet2.Cells(i, j)) = LCase(Me.TextBox2) Or H = 1 And _
 ws.Cells(i, j) = Val(Me.TextBox2) Then
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
 For X = 1 To 8
 Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, X - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, X)
 Next X
 End If
 Next j
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Now that you're generalized your Sub, you can modify the value of `ws` to repeat the code as much as you need to. If it is every sheet in your workbook, you can use a `For Each` loop, like

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook
    'All your code for the ws here
Next ws
```

Or, you can define the worksheets in an array beforehand.

```
Dim SheetList(0 to 2) As String
Dim k As Integer

SheetList(0) = "Sheet 2 Name"
SheetList(1) = "Sheet 4 Name"
SheetList(2) = "Sheet 3 Name"
SheetList(3) = "Sheet 6 Name"

For k = LBound(SheetList) To UBound(SheetList)
    ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetList(k))
    'The rest of your code from above
Next k
```

You didn't specify in your question what kind of sheets how many, or how they are organized. But, these options should be enough to get you where you are trying to go.

Comment: Hi SandPiper, thank you but unfortunately I am getting an error code at ws = ActiveWorkbook ...... "This object does not support this method"

Comment: You need to **Set** ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetList(k)). Object type vars are Set, not simple assignment.

Comment: @SandPiper thank you I have managed to do get it working by changing ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SheetList(k)) to Set ws = Sheets(SheetList(k))

Comment: @Kev Using `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheet2` will only work if `Sheet2` is the actual name in VBA, not the caption. I'm glad you got it working though!